# I am unable to see(drop down) available resource groups under subscription in ARM template deployment in azure devops release pipleline task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy my ADF ARM template through azure devops cicd , I have create build pipeline to keep my artifect file , now i want to create release pipeline deploy into QA/prod, for this i have create a release pipeline with task “ARM template deployment” and I have created a service connection from Service principal which is having subscription level contributor access .
Below are azure configuration i have given :

Deployment scope:Resource Group
Azure Resource Manager connection: given the created one which having subscription level access(role:contributor)
Subscription:
after this i am unable to get listed resources groups(drop down) under this subscription , i have tried to hardcode mine but giving error in release phase :
Failed to check the resource group status. Error: {“statusCode”:403}.

i have tried to hardcode mine but giving error in release phase :
Failed to check the resource group status. Error: {“statusCode”:403}.

Comment: Do you have a resource group in the supported regions for ADF? Why use ARM instead of Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with the following steps to fix the issue:

1. Ensure there is at least one Resource Group under the Azure Subscription that the ARM service connection is connecting to.
2. Ensure the Service Principal used on the ARM service connection has the required role permissions on the Resource Groups.
3. When creating the ARM service connection, if select a Resource Group, the access scope of the connection will be limited within the selected Resource Group. In this situation, on the ARM template deployment task, you can only see the selected Resource Group and no other Resource Groups from the drop-down list.

   [image]

Comment: - Thanks for your quick response , i am able to get resource list after SPN get the enough access